# Move stderr fd pointer to start

Tags: c, linux, stderr

I'm writing a wrapper that forks an `execv()` process.  Output from the child is captured in `stderr`.  When `waitpid()` releases, I can read the contents of `stderr` and report it back.

In my case, I want to dynamically allocate a buffer and write `stderr` into this buffer.

To size the buffer I can `realloc()`, but this is not very efficient and I have found it tends to bloat memory pool use.  Rather, I'd like to know the size without altering its pointer.

Consider the following, and note that `MyStderr` is just a placeholder for `stderr`:

```
int size=0;
int ch=0;
// int MyStderr is the stderr fd
FILE *nCountFD = fdopen(MyStderr, "r");
while ((ch = getc(nCountFD)!=EOF)
{
    ++size;
}
printf("Size is %ld\n", size);
```

Here I get the size.  However, now the file pointer for `MyStderr` is at the end of its buffer.

I tried using `lseek`.

`lseek()` fails against `stderr`, so I can't use it here.  At least, this is what my testing and stackoverflow searching indicates.

So ...

1. Is there a way to get the size without moving `MyStderr` to eof ?

or

1. Is there an `lseek` method that will work with `MyStderr` ?

Note.  Here is the only solution I can think of, using `realloc`..

```
char *buf=(char*)malloc(80);
char *NewBuf=NULL;
int n=80;
while ((ch = getc(nCountFD)!=EOF)
{
    buf[i]=ch;
    ++size;
    if (size>n)
    {
       n=n+80;
       NewBuf= realloc(buf, n);
       // some code to make sure it works here //
       buf=NewBuf;
    }
}
printf("Size is %ld\n", size);
```

---

### And now the update

Rather than build the functionality to work around the fact that stderr is unbuffered, I determined to make the initial malloc of my result buffer sufficiently large so that realloc() would be unlikely in the majority of cases.  And if realloc() happens, the original allocation is doubled in size for each realloc() as suggested.

In testing (100000 iterations) this works very well with no leaking or discernible bloating.

I owe a great deal to the Stack Overflow community.  Thank you all.

The code below won't run stand-alone.  It's placed here to illustrate what I did.

.. 
after all the code that parses the commandline, forks, does execv, and cleans up...

```
while (waitpid(nPID, &status, 0) != nPID)
    ;
i = 0;
nFD = fdopen(nErrFD, "r");
if (!nFD) {
    snprintf(cErrMsg, 80, "Cannot open fd[%i].  Failed to spaw process",
            nErrFD);
    cbuf = strcpy(cbuf, cErrMsg);
    goto NECerror;
}

close(nErrFD);


cbuf = calloc(nBufSz, sizeof(char));
memset(cbuf, 0x00, nBufSz);
i = 0;
while ((ch = getc(nFD)) != EOF) {
    cbuf[i] = (char) ch;
    ++size;
    ++i;
    if (size > nBufSz) {
        nBufSz = nBufSz + nBaseBufSz;
        NewBuf = realloc(cbuf, nBufSz);
        if (NewBuf == NULL) {
            snprintf(cErrMsg, 80,
                    "Internal error:cannot allocate [%i] bytes", nBufSz);
            cbuf = strcpy(cbuf, cErrMsg);
            fclose(nFD);
            goto NECerror;
        }
        cbuf = NewBuf;
        free(NewBuf);
    }

}
fclose(nFD);
```

Comment: Memory fragmentation due to `realloc()`ating memory might be reduced if you use an exponental increase but a linear. So do not just add a constant number of characters but double the amount of memory allocated from reallocation to reallocation. At the end you could place a final `realloc()`ation which then shrinks the memory allocated down to the size really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes are not seekable -- if you're reading data from a pipe that's being provided by the other process, then you cannot seek its data stream.  You have to store the data as its read.

The reason you're probably seeing lots of memory thrashing is due to the way your expanding your buffer -- you only expand it by a constant amount every time it's exceeded.  You'll have much better success if you *double* its size when it's exceeded: this is a well-known technique for [dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

For example:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
size_t size = 4096;
char *buf = malloc(size);
char *bufPtr = buf;
ssize_t n;
while((n = read(MyStderr, bufPtr, 4096) > 0)
{
    bufPtr += n;

    // Make sure we always have at least 4096 bytes of free space in the
    // buffer for the next read
    if(size - (bufPtr - buf) < 4096)
    {
        size *= 2;  // Watch out for overflow!
        buf = realloc(buf, size);
    }
}

// The (bufPtr - buf) bytes of buf now hold the entirety of the process's stderr
```

Comment: Maybe the adding amount should be limited resp. the factor decreased - at some time, maybe around 10..100 MiB or so, doubling the buffer size might be exaggerated.

Comment: Maybe, but by that point you have a serious design problem: you should not be buffering hundreds of MB in the first place, you should be processing it as a stream as it comes in.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: yours is a good suggestion.  Coupling with that from glglgl, it seems best to increment the realloc as buf=realloc(buf,size+original_size); where original_size is set to 4096 also.

Answer (score 2):

Can you write the output from `stderr` into a temporary file?  Then you can have the ability to seek randomly throughout the file, check the size, use `mmap()` on it, etc.  You can even do these while you're still receiving data.

Comment: I had considered this, but it will slow things down considerably.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, pipes are not seekable. All this means, however, is that you need to ensure `stderr` is not a pipe. In the wrapper, before `execv`, do

```
close( STDERR_FILENO );
open( error_log_path, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC ); // opens into STDERR_FILENO
```

The `open` call is guaranteed to set the standard error stream because the lowest free file descriptor is always the one assigned.

Then, the `fork` should duplicate the file descriptor, so the parent process sits at byte zero while the child starts writing from the beginning. There is no need to seek.

This assumes you aren't also trying to pipe the error output somewhere else at the same time. In that case, the child process would have to duplicate the error output to the externally-visible pipe and the parent's buffering file, or you would have to stream through the parent instead of using `waitpid`, with the child `stderr` and parent `stderr` being two *different* pipes.

Comment: I wonder if this technique will work when other apps, using the same function, open error_log_path?

Comment: Absolutely correct - "redirection" is *definitely* an option in this scenario.

Comment: @MarkRichards Only one process may write the file, and readers should not truncate it, obviously. It is just regular file I/O. What is your concern?

Comment: @Potatoswatter That it would be clobbered, or cause deadlock.  Also I'd like to avoid writing to a file/device (embedded system/memory and cpu concerns).

Comment: @MarkRichards: On an embedded system with synchronization and memory concerns, I would highly recommend doing things properly and avoiding `waitpid`. There is no reason given to block at all, or to buffer up an indefinite amount of output. File I/O *never* causes deadlocks unless you add an inter-process lock. Merely reading a file never clobbers it. Writing to a file is usually safer than writing to RAM, in terms of running out of memory, especially on a system with virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

No - stderr is unbuffered.  Your only choice is to buffer the input yourself.  I'd recommend implementing a circular buffer (if you can afford to lose the oldest output), or just create a fixed buffer of some "max sizse".  IMHO...